# Determine if a button isn't clickable with Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

Doing

```
onView(withId(R.id.login_button)).check(matches(isClickable()));
```

is useful for verifying if a button *is* clickable. How would I verify that a button *isn't* clickable?

Edit: Like I said, it only tells me if it `isClickable`. I'm looking for a way to verify it **IS NOT** clickable.

Comment: Go ahead and link me to where my question has been answered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a button is clickable in espresso test, android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906881/checking-if-a-button-is-clickable-in-espresso-test-android-studio)

Comment: Yeah--like I posted--that only checks if it IS clickable. I want to make sure it ISN'T clickable.

Comment: If it is not-not able to be clickable, it is not clickable. Matthews answer should work. What does that line return?

Comment: I get an error in Android Studio--it says it isn't possible. That was the first thing I tried. I already extensively searched around and didn't find an answer to my question--hence posting here.

Comment: @Nxt3 I've found the correct solution for your problem. Have a look at my new answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ## 2023 Update
>
> [isNotClickable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers#isNotClickable())

```
onView(withId(R.id.button)).check(matches(isNotClickable()))
```

[Source](https://cs.android.com/androidx/android-test/+/master:espresso/core/java/androidx/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.java)

```
public static Matcher<View> isNotClickable() {
    return new IsClickableMatcher(false);
}
```

> #### Edit - Original Solution
>
> Use not(), it returns a matcher that negates the matcher passed to it.

You're looking for: `not( isClickable() )`

```
onView(withId(R.id.login_button)).check(matches( not(isClickable()) ));
```

---

> **Breaking down the code**

`onView()` returns the UI object we are interested in (`login_button` in this case), and we call `.check` on this object to see if our assertion holds.

The `matches` function returns an assertion that we build by passing in a `Matcher`. The `isClickable()` function returns a Matcher that we can give back to `matches()`.

`not()` is a Matcher which returns a Matcher negating the logic of the one given to it.

So this code is checking if the assertion `not( isClickable() )` is true on the `login_button` View.

Comment: Yep; not a thing here.

Comment: @Nxt3 It certainly is. Could you post the error that android studio gives you?

Comment: @Nxt3 I'm sorry, I put the `!` in the wrong place. It should have been outside of the **matches** function. I've edited my answer now, let me know if that works.

Comment: Still not a thing. It isn't booleans. Those are `ViewAssertions`; you can' use `!` anywhere in that call.

Comment: @Nxt3 You're completely right. In a very early version of Espresso (the one I have some experience with), you could reverse the logic of a ViewMatcher with the ! operator. I see that is no longer the case. I have edited my question and now it contains a solution to your problem. It is not a perfect solution, so I'll keep looking until I find that perfect solution and edit my answer once more. Until then, you can use my current work-around.

Comment: @Nxt3 I've found the correct solution, have a look at my new answer.